# How to use natural language processing to map text to a preset list of topics

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I'm interested in being able to use a service such as Google's Natural Language API to classify random user questions into a preset list of topics.  I have an advanced level of programming experience, and want to use Google's service as a base and if necessary build a codebase around it to accomplish our goal.  An example use case would be:

Hardcoded preset list of topics:
Baseball
Football
Soccer

Sample user questions and expected results:
How do I cook pasta?  RESULT: No results
What is a referee?  RESULT: Baseball/Football/Soccer
What is a home run?  RESULT: Baseball

1) Does anything like this already exist to classify random user text into preset list of topics?
2) If not, is there a programming concept that already exists that shows ways to implement this, or allow me to learn the concepts around this? (I searched on Google and couldn't find anything -- I may simply not know what to look for)
3) If not, any guidance on this could be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a basic classification problem, or more specifically maybe **intent classification**.

Google has [a guide](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/classify-text-tutorial) to creating a classification program. You should start with that.

The output of the classifier there will give you a list of topics with a probability for each. If you want to allow multiple probabilities, which is harder to get right, you can take all topics with a probability above a threshold. You'll have to determine the threshold with experimentation.

The default model has a fixed list of categories, but [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/no-deep-learning-experience-needed-build-a-text-classification-model-with-google-cloud-automl-natural-language) walks you through setting up custom categories.

---

If you are willing to look outside Google Cloud it may be easier to find guides to text classification. spaCy has [an excellent guide](https://spacy.io/usage/training#textcat) you can use to get rolling quickly.